# Getting foreign key values from Django values()

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am getting  data objects from Django models using

```
tabledata=Entity.objects.filter(quarter=1)
```

Using this method, I am able to extract the values of the  objects specified by the foreign key like so

```
tabledata[0].creator.name
```

However when I changed the code to

```
tabledata=Entity.objects.filter(quarter=1).values()
```

I can extract only foreign key values but not the values of the object data linked with the foreign key. Something like

```
tabledata[0][creator][name]  does not work
```

Is there a way to extract the values this way?

Comment: This is *one* of the many reasons why using `.values()` is not a good idea: it erodes the logical layer of the model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookup in `.values()` like this:

```
entities = Entity.objects.filter(quarter=1).values('creator__name')
print(entities[0]['creator__name'])
```

You can fetch other fields too if you need:

```
Entity.objects.filter(quarter=1).values('creator__name', 'direct_field', 'another_direct_field')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *one* of the many reasons why using [**`.values()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) is not a good idea: it erodes the logical layer of the model.

You can use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to add the name to the values:

```
from django.db.models import F

tabledata = Entity.objects.filter(quarter=1).annotate(
    creator_name=F('creator__name')
).values()
```

Then it will appear under the `'creator_name'` key in the dictionary.

But using `.values()` is often only useful in specific usecases. For example a `GROUP BY` on a specific value, or in a subquery. You should make use of serializers if you want to make JSON for a given model.